# Laravel eloquent Update Function

Tags: laravel, api, eloquent, insert-update

Using Laravel eloquent in Modular development. Save works well, But the Update function not working as I expected. Kindly check my coding method and error.

```
use Modules\Projects\Entities\Project;
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $project = Modules\Projects\Entities\Project::find($id);
        $project->project_name = request('project_name');
        $project->save();
}
```

Error throws like:

```
{
    "message": "Class 'Modules\\Projects\\Http\\Controllers\\Modules\\Projects\\Entities\\Project' not found",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError",
    "file": "D:\\XMAPP\\htdocs\\minidmsapi\\Modules\\Projects\\Http\\Controllers\\ProjectsController.php",
    "line": 69,
    "trace": [
```

How to use " `$flight = App\Flight::find(1);`" in modular development ?
[Laravel Official Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#updates)

Comment: Write this above : use App\Modules\Projects\Entities\Project;

Comment: And change to this : $project = Project::find($id);

Comment: @YasinPatel thanks. Working Fine. How to get Success Response ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already imported the `Modules\Projects\Entities\Project;`.Now you can directly use `Project`.

```
use Modules\Projects\Entities\Project;
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $project = Project::find($id);
    $project->project_name = request('project_name');
    $project->save();
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: ok. How to get Success Response? ( I mean Saved ID for check ) @jithesh

Comment: `$project = Project::where('id', $id)->update(['project_name' => request('project_name')]);`.Then use `$project->id`

Answer (score 1):

try adding `\` before `Modules\Projects\Entities\Project::find($id);`.

like `\Modules\Projects\Entities\Project::find($id);`

or you can directly use `Project::find($id);` as you have already used namespace.

Comment: @Vibhaa ok. How to get Success Response? ( I mean Saved ID for check )

Comment: just check `$project->id` is set or not

Answer (score 1):

You dont' have to use full namespace on `Project` model, since you already imported it at the top:

```
use Modules\Projects\Entities\Project;
```

Just use:

```
$project = Project::find($id);
```

Edit:
To return some response messages, below you can add something like this at the end of your function:

```
return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Your message');
```

In order to display your message in blade, add something like this:

```
@if (session()->has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <p>{{session('success')}}</p>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: ok. How to get Success Response? ( I mean Saved ID for check )

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You want a message that says "Updated project id 10 (for example) ? "

Comment: @zlatna Exactly